# Angular Material Paginator under the hood

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can someone explain to me how Material paginator is working under the hood in Angular 10+? I have a material table with search (filtering) and sorting and I need to always keep the top 4 records of the datasource visible in the table as they are totals on their types but I'd like the rest of the lines to change when paginating. Would that be posible? I've managed to make sorting work for all rows except the top ones. Thank you!

Comment: Before existing paginations relations with a MatDataSource, the pagination it's only use a [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe). Really you can use a mat-pagination "alone" and each time you change the source give values to the length and page and use a pipe slice in your table. But I suggest another approach that is use a Table with multiple header (you can see one in the [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

Comment: example is good, thank you! the project I'm on requests that the pagination values also include the top rows so if it's set to 10 and first 4 rows are fixed, you actually just change 6 rows when clicking next or previous. I think the example you gave combined with the slice pipe might be a good solution.